# Recursive PropertyInformation from Nested IEnumerable<Model>

Tags: c#

I am having trouble getting the property Names of the IEnumerable properties in my models. I cant seem to get the Nested IEnumerables from the TModel classes. I have looked into some reflection examples but haven't something quite along these lines.

I am looking to just get the IEnumerable property names for each nested model and send the property name to a list. The actual value is not important.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// TModel = DataContent in this context.
public class GetModelBase<TModel>
{
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TModel> DataContent { get; set; }
}

public class DataContent
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Data> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int DataId{ get; set; }
    IEnumerable<DataInformation> DataInformation{ get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<GetModelBase<TModel>> ResponseAsList<TModel>()
{
    // ResponseBody in this context is a string representation of json of the models above...
    var toArray = new ConvertJsonArray<GetModelBase<TModel>>(ResponseBody).ReturnJsonArray();
}

// T = GetModelBase<DataContent> in this context.
public class ConvertJsonArray<T>
{
    public ConvertJsonArray(string responseString)
    {
        _responseString = responseString;
        Convert();
    }

    public void Convert()
    {
        var result = JObject.Parse(_responseString);

        // This is where I am having trouble... I am unable to get the nested IEnumerable names.
        Type t = typeof(T);
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInformation = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);

        List<string> toLists = new List<string>();
        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in propertyInformation)
            toLists.Add(pi.Name);

        // End of Property Information Issuse...

        foreach (string s in toLists.ToArray())
        {
            if (result[s] != null)
            {
                if (!(result[s] is JArray)) result[s] = new JArray(result[s]);
            }
        }

        _jsonAsArray = result.ToString();
    }

    public string ReturnJsonArray()
    {
        return _jsonAsArray;
    }

    private string _responseString { get; set; }
    private string _jsonAsArray { get; set; }
}
```

The result I am looking for in the above code sample would be a list containing only the IEnumerable names as such { "DataContent", "Data", "DataInformation" }

UPDATE:

I am still having trouble looping through each model. I have a nearly working code example.

```
// This replaces the Type code in the Convert method...
GetProperties(typeof(T))

private void GetProperties(Type classType)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in classType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && (property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
        {
            ValuesToList.Add(property.Name);

            foreach (Type nestedType in property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments())
            {
                GetProperties(nestedType);
            }
        }
    }
}

private List<string> ValuesToList { get; set; }
```

The results for this yields { "DataContent", "Data" } but fails to get "DataInformation". For some reason the IEnumerables are not hit while in the foreach loop. Additional help would be appreciated.

Comment: When I run that sample (at least after bringing it into a stand-alone form), I am getting `Error` and `DataContent` in `result`. Is your question how to recognize which ones of those are of type `IEnumerable<...>`?

Comment: Yes they should only show the IEnumerable Property Names but not just for the ModelBase but also for the DataContent, Data, and DataInformation lists. I want to get all possible IEnumerable property names from each nested object.

Comment: Ah, right - I guess I killed that recursion when converting the example into something compileable. Either way, I've explained the required filter condition in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43402711/1430156).

Comment: The filter works beautifully but I am still having some trouble with my recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the [`PropertyInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), so you are almost there - all that is left is to recognize which properties are of type `IEnumerable<...>`, where `...` can be an arbitrary type.

For this purpose, check the [`PropertyType` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx).
It is a [`Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) instance for which you can check whether it is based upon the generic type definition `IEnumerable<T>` by means of the [`GetGenericTypeDefinition` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx).
That method will throw an exception for non-generic types, so you will also have to check [`IsGenericType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType
    && (pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
{
    toLists.Add(pi.Name);
}
```